# Sort on multimap<pair<T,T>,P>

Tags: c++, multimap

I have written a sort class to sort the multimap, but when I insert element into the map, the following compiler error appears:

```
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\xutility(313) : error C2664: 'bool MapSort::operator ()(std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &,std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>' to 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &'
```

can anybody help?

```
class MapSort
{
    public:
        MapSort();
        ~MapSort();

        public:
            bool operator() ( pair<T,T>& i, pair<T,T>& j) 
            {
                return i.first.GetID() < j.first.GetID();

            }

};


multimap < pair < T,T >,P > CurrMap;
CurrMap.insert( multimap < pair < T, T >,Metric >::value_type(make_pair< T,T >(aAttractionA,aAttractionB),CurrP))
//
```

Comment: I have formatted your post. Please read the FAQ and preview pane in the future.

Comment: See also: [Strict weak ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_weak_ordering)

Answer (score 1):

```
pair<T,T>& i  and pair<T,T>& j
```

should be

```
pair<T,T> const& i and pair<T,T> const& j
```

(reference)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `const`-correctness:

```
bool operator()(pair<T,T> const& i, pair<T,T> const& j) const
{
    return i.first.GetID() < j.first.GetID();
}
```

- Nothing in this function needs to be mutable, so "why not" make the function and its inputs `const`?
- In fact, this is *expected* of you by the contracts of the container.

In addition, I'm not sure that your own sort ordering here is valid or that it makes sense. It certainly doesn't seem entirely purposeful. `pair<T,T>` already sorts naturally: if anything, you might have a `bool operator<` for your type `T`.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I have modified acccordingly by adding "const&",but the compiler now flaks "error C2662: 'T::GetID' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const T' to 'T &'
1>        Conversion loses qualifiers"

Comment: @cool: Huh? Which part of my answer denoted adding another `&`? Where did you add it? That's probably wrong. Do what I said in my answer.

Comment: I have added the const, but the compiler reports other error:error C2662: 'T::GetID' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const T' to 'T&'                 Conversion loses qualifiers" .

Comment: @cool: What Matthieu said. Sounds like you need to have a think about `const`-correctness throughout your program.

Answer (score 0):

Your sort predicate must take `const` references.

Plus, aren't multi-maps already sorted?

Comment: Yes, but he's defining his own sort ordering. Nothing wrong with that in principle (though I'm not entirely convinced here).